# Javascript function on multiple tables in one ASP.net Update Panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, pageload

I am stuck with a problem where I have multiple tables in an update panel. I bind the ASP.net gridview items from code behind when I click an ASP.net button. This causes a postback which triggers my javascript pageLoad functions.

Inside the pageLoad block I have following function which gets the length of the table and either displays a detailed view if the length is 2 (one row) or displays the table when the length is more than 2. This works well.

```
    $(function () {
        var len = $("#<%=gvClave.ClientID%> tr").length;
        if (len > 2) {
            document.getElementById('frameClaveTable').style.display = 'block';
            $('#<%=gvClave.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({
                width: $('#frameClaveTable').width(),
                height: 200
            });
            $('#sliderClaveTable').animate({ width: $('#frameClaveTable').width() + 50 });
        } else if (len == 2) {
            showClaveDetails($("#<%=gvClave.ClientID%> tr"));
        }
    });
```

I have a third table in the same update panel which I bind when I search for a value in the SQL database. During the postback when I bind the third table I would expect the other tables to be reset and disappear from view. However in the postback pageLoad event the old table is still found and displayed again. I can't get my head around how to prevent this. I have tried to force a postback prior to refreshing the tables. I have tried to put the tables in seperate update panels but to no avail.

Any ideas on this issues are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. I wrongly thought that a postback will clear all gridviews in the update panel where the postback occurs. I now set the datasource of the second table to nothing and bind the table in the code behind function before I bind the first table.